# Pinging win2k16 returns an IPv6 address instead of IPv4

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I have one win2k16 VM, when I ping it locally, it returns always IPv6. I 
-disabled the IPv6 stack on the NIC, 
- did ipconfig /flushdns so many times, 
- downloaded and applied a fix from MS

> Prefer IPv4 over IPv6 in prefix policies

at 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/how-to-disable-ipv6-or-its-components-in-windows

still when pinging locally the response is

> ::1

When I ping from any other machine I get the IPv4

Comment: Disabling IPv6 is not supported in Windows. Disabling IPv4 is perfectly fine though. In any case, `localhost` _is_ `::1` and you need to deal with this now instead of trying to hide from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can force ping to use IPv4.

```
ping -4 localhost
```

Comment: I know this sir, this is not what I am looking for because I have some applications running on the same machine and it seems that they are not getting the right IP while configuring them. When I hardcode the IP4 directly everything goes well but when giving FQDN or netbios it does not go through